# Как передать параметр в функцию React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент который принимает в себя пропс ID и выводит информацию которая содержит этот ID.

Пытаюсь сделать изменение информации по клику, но ничего не выходит. [image: Передача параметров в функцию react js]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. При клике нужно передать коллбэк функцию в которой изменить state render на тот что нам нужно.

[image: решение]

Comment: элементарно блин, тупая моя голова...